# What is the list of minimum services needed to run Steam on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, services, steam

There are a lot of services running in the background for windows 7. If one is using there windows computer only to play steam games, then I am willing to bet that a good chunk of the services running in the background are not needed, and either setting them to manual or uninstalling them will improve the performance of running Steam on windows 7. I believe this can be done by typing "services.msc" in the Run box. I am not sure if the services should be either set to manual or uninstalled. What is the list of minimum services needed to run Steam on windows 7?

Comment: You are going to see minimal performance gains by doing this.

Comment: steam is pretty lightweight. I assume you mean games?

Comment: Yes. I was referring to steam games.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ASP.net is the only service required to receive updates automatically. I only know this, because I also have been rooting out services that I do not need.

Also, do not pay attention to the people who say "you will only see minimum gains". DPC procedure call latency is naturally huge in all Windows operating systems. When you disable un-needed services and features, you can decrease this latency quite a bit.

I would also look into selectively removing some Windows updates. There were some updates in the past that have unintentionally (and in some cases, as a by-product) caused DPC latency to increase drastically.

So far with the changes I have made, I have nearly eliminated any noticeable DPC latency. You will always have some, as DPC procedure calls are an inherent part of any Windows based operation.

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)